# Does adding the same listener to a control/property allocate extra memory for the listener spot?

Tags: java, properties, controls, listener

When creating a listener like:

```
InvalidationListener progressListener = new InvalidationListener() {
    public void invalidated(Observable o) {
        updateValues();
    }
};
```

and then adding the listener multiple times to the same instance/property like:

```
model.getMediaPlayer().currentTimeProperty().addListener(progressListener);
```

Since `model.getMediaPlayer()` changes and can reference back the same one as one referenced before. Would adding the same listener, `progressListener` in this case, cause any problems like leaking memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the listener once and then add it multiple times, the amount of memory used is tiny. However, tiny allocated many, many times can add up. Listeners are a potential source of leaks, but usually when new instances are created each time. I doubt that the source of your leak, given what you described.